# Android listview select default item

Tags: android, listview, selector

I am trying to highlight by default a position in my listview.

Here is the code:
My listview declaration:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Item list declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:textSize="20sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my custom selector I have:

```
   <item 
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" 
    android:state_selected="true"/>
```

And now I want to mark with green by default a position in my listview.
Java code:

```
listview.setSelector(R.drawable.listselector);
listview.setSelection(20);
```

But the selected element is not highlighted with the green color. I tried lot of proposed solutions found, but nothing worked.
Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the selector in the `ListView` XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector"
    />
```

Also, define the selector `item` like this:

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
```

instead of `android:drawable`.

Comment: please share the rest of your code. The full selector XML and the class from which you set the selection. Did you remember to remove `listview.setSelector(R.drawable.listselector);` after adding it to the XML?

Answer (score 1):

### use this

#### your_list_view.setItemChecked(0,true); // "0" is selectable item position

Worked for me :)